# why does this select not work

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to learn sql and I get this error - what does it mean?.

I'm trying to : Get countries that have a GDP greater than any country in Europe?

Error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Subquery returned more
>   than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=,
>   <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   (SQL-21000)

```
select name, gdp from bbc 
where gdp > 
(
    select gdp from bbc
    where region = 'Europe'
)
```

Comment: There are several Europe regions in `bbc`. You cannot compare scalar value to list.

Comment: Uhmmm, isn't it obvious by reading the error message? You can only use a subquery with the > operator when the subquery only returns a single value.

Comment: You are probably better explaining what you want to achieve to get better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message describes the error adequately: your table has many countries in Europe, so `>` operator cannot be applied without some aggregation or more constraints in the subquery:

```
select name, gdp from bbc 

where gdp > 

(
select max(gdp) from bbc
where region = 'Europe'

)
```

Adding `max` ensures that there would be precisely one number selected, and that number is the highest GDP among all European countries<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> You might as well select the GDP of Germany right away :)

Answer (score 3):

This means that the query `select gdp from bbc where region = 'Europe'` returns more than 1 row and the `where gpd >` condition can't compare against multiple values. You will need to update the query to only return 1 row.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of the error is that your subquery returns multiple values.

Depending on your requirements, you should use either this query, if you need `gdp` to be greater than **EACH** of the Europe's GDP's:

```
SELECT
  name,
  gdp
FROM
  bbc 
WHERE gdp > 
  (
    SELECT
      MAX(gdp)
    FROM
      bbc
    WHERE
      region = 'Europe'
  )
```

Or this one, if you need `gdp` to be greater than **AT LEAST ONE** of the Europe's GDP's (the difference is just `MIN` vs `MAX`):

```
SELECT
  name,
  gdp
FROM
  bbc 
WHERE gdp > 
  (
    SELECT
      MIN(gdp)
    FROM
      bbc
    WHERE
      region = 'Europe'
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

run this part of your query

select gdp from bbc where region = 'Europe'

if it is returning more than 1 row it will fail.  You need to be more selective in the where clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with one value - based on `Min , Max or TOP 1`

Nota : You can't compare one value with collection.

```
select name, gdp from bbc 

where gdp > 

(select TTOP(1) gdp from bbc where region = 'Europe')
```

Or

```
 select name, gdp from bbc 

    where gdp > 

    (select Max(gdp) from bbc where region = 'Europe')
```

Answer (score 1):

**Nice place to dust off academic [ANY operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175064.aspx)!**

```
select name, gdp from bbc 
where gdp > ANY
(
select gdp from bbc
where region = 'Europe'
)
```

"... greater than **ANY** country in Europe ...". Just like answer.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs when the inner query returns more than 1 value. Try:

```
select name, gdp from bbc where gdp > (select TOP 1 gdp from bbc where region = 'Europe')
```